# Send TextBox text to user control

Tags: winforms, textbox, user-controls

I have a question and I am unsure on how to proceed and am seeking some directions.

Here's my scenario, I have a Form1 with a panel1, I can load 3 different User Controls inside panel1 (UserControl1, UserControl2 and UserControl3) inside each one of these user controls I can open Form2 which has a few TextBoxes.

What I need is to whenever I hit a button on my Form2 all the TextBox text be sent to the User Control that opened Form2.

I'm not sure if my question here is clear, if anyone can help me with that I appreciate, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you are creating the new form. Check [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/390991/how-to-pass-values-from-child-form-to-parent-form) it contains the two scenarios.

Child Form:

```
public partial class Child : Form
    {
        public event NotifyParentHandler NotifyParent;
        public delegate void NotifyParentHandler(string textValue);

        public Child()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    private void btnNotify_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //assuming that you want to send the value when clicking a button
        if (this.NotifyParent != null)
        {
            this.NotifyParent(textBox1.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

Parent Form

```
public partial class Parent : Form
    {
        private Child childForm;

        public Parent()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    private void btnOpenChildForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Open the child form
        childForm = new Child();
        childForm.NotifyParent += childForm_NotificationTriggered;
        childForm.ShowDialog();
    }

    void childForm_NotificationTriggered(string textValuePassed)
    {
       //here you can do anything 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked perfectly!
Can you please tell me what you just did so I can read more about it?

Thanks again.

Comment: hey - if this worked for you, can you accept it as an answer plz.